# In Angular CSS class 'open' append always to side navigation bar when user logged in, due to which sidebar always open with sub-items

Tags: angular

I am using core UI angular admin template library
link:- https://coreui.io/angular/

[image]

As stated above I am facing an issue where side navigation bar always expanded when user logged into the system. On inspection I have found that the CSS class `open` always append with the navigation items.

Please find the snippet below :-

[image]

The problem is an admin user is authorized to view 20 modules when admin logins, then the side navigation bar will go beyond the browser due to this issue.

What I want to figure out when user login to the system all navigation items should remains closed.

**PLEASE NOTE :- The problem occurs when dynamic JSON renders, It is working fine with static JSON.**

**TEMPLATE**

```
<app-sidebar #appSidebar [fixed]="true" [display]="'lg'" [minimized]="sidebarMinimized" (minimizedChange)="toggleMinimize($event)">
    <app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="appSidebar.minimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
    <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
  </app-sidebar>
```

**DYNAMIC RESPONSE (JSON) FROM SERVER**

```
[{
    "name": "Configuration",
    "url": null,
    "icon": null,
    "displayOrder": 1,
    "children": [{
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage Role",
        "url": "configurations/manage_roles",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }, {
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage Permission",
        "url": "configurations/manage_permissions",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }, {
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage User",
        "url": "configurations/manage_user",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Dashboard",
    "url": null,
    "icon": null,
    "displayOrder": 2,
    "children": [{
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Add User",
        "url": "dashboard/add_user",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Subscription Platform",
    "url": null,
    "icon": null,
    "displayOrder": 3,
    "children": [{
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage Client",
        "url": "subscription/manage_client",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }, {
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage Package",
        "url": "subscription/manage_package",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }, {
        "privilegeOrder": 3,
        "subMenuIcon": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "Manage Product",
        "url": "subscription/manage_product",
        "permission": "EDIT"
    }]
}]
```

**STATIC JSON**

```
{
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Configurations',
    url: '/configurations',
    icon: 'icon-settings',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Manage Users',
        url: '/configurations/manage_user',
        icon: 'icon-people'
      },
      {
        name: 'Manage Roles',
        url: '/configurations/manage_roles',
        icon: 'icon-badge'
      },
      {
        name: 'Manage Permissions',
        url: '/configurations/manage_permissions',
        icon: 'icon-ban'
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Subscriptions',
    url: '/subscriptions',
    icon: 'icon-map',
    children: [
    
      {
        name: 'Manage Client',
        url: '/subscription/manage-client',
        icon: 'icon-paper-plane'
      },
      
      {
        name: 'Subscription',
        url: '/subscription',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Subscription Plan',
        url: '/subscription/subscription-plan',
        icon: 'icon-paper-plane'
      },
      {
        name: 'Manage Product',
        url: '/subscription/manage-product',
        icon: 'icon-folder'
      }
     
    ]
  }
```

I am not able to figure out why it is working for fake response and not working for the actual response

Please provide me the best solution

Comment: in dynamic JSON there are some values null like Id, name, icon etc. have you checked if those are causing issue?

Comment: It is working now, we have fix the API response.
Thanks

Comment: you are welcome and happy coding!